# How can I replace `SELECT ... WHERE SELECT ...` with joins?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join

I have read that `SELECT ... WHERE SELECT ...` is slow, and that I should use joins instead.

But I don't know how to replace this code

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
Where
    (
        Data1 IS NULL
        OR
        (
            Data2=1
            AND
            (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.Id=Table1.Id) IS NULL
        )
    )
    AND
    (SELECT 1 FROM Table3 WHERE Table3.Id=Table1.Id) IS NULL
```

with joins.

The tables have the following structure:

Table1:

- Id: INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
- Data1: XML
- Data2: INTEGER

Table2:

- Id: INTEGER

Table3:

- Id: INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Comment: PDO won't help you with it.

Comment: first look at the EXPLAIN to see if there is a problem that the optimizer does not address - then you can worry about tuning - as opposed to trying to follow a global rule.

Comment: @Randy I have never understood how to use EXPLAIN. If I just write EXPLAIN before my query and run it on phpliteadmin, it only says "*0 row(s) affected*"

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: @CL. When I run EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN I also get "*0 row(s) affected*", with no results

Comment: Then run it in any other tool, like `sqlite3`.

Comment: @Randy,CL. With `fetchAll` I can do `EXPLAIN` (I guess phpliteadmin uses `exec`). But with `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` I don't have enough information to know which way is better, and I don't understand `EXPLAIN` information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Id from Table1 where
  Id not in (select Id from Table3) and
  (Data1 is null or 
   (Data2 = 1 and Id not in (select Id from Table2)));
```

or, if you really want joins:

```
select Id from Table1 left join Table2 on (Table1.Id = Table2.Id)
  left join Table3 on (Table1.Id = Table3.Id)
where Table3.Id is null and
  (Data1 is null or
   (Data2 = 1 and Table2.Id is null));
```

I don't expect much difference in performance between these two. The query would likely benefit from an index on Table2.Id (you have one on Table3.Id by virtue of it being a primary key).

Comment: Thanks! But after creating the index on Table2, `Id not in (select Id from Table2)` doesn't use it, but `not exists (select 1 from Table2 where Table2.Id=Table1.Id)` does, and it seems it takes the same time than with joins

Answer (score 0):

There are two key parts to moving subqueries from `in` to the `from` clause.  The first is to use `left outer join`, so no rows from the first table inadvertently drop out.  The second is to use `select distinct` for each subquery, to avoid unwanted duplicates.

Applied to your query, the result is:

```
SELECT t1.Id
FROM Table1 t1 left outer join
     (select distinct id
      from Table2
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left outer join
     (select distinct id
      from Table3
     ) t3
     on t1.id = t3.id
Where(t1.Data1 IS NULL OR
      (t1.Data2=1 and t2.id is null)
     ) and
     t3.id is null;
```

Comment: When I run your code I get "*ERROR: near "from": syntax error*"